# Photoshop Lighting Effects differs from preview

Tags: adobe-photoshop, filter

I try to apply a Lighting effects filter to create a stone texture, like in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BvuuWE6GlVw) tutorial. The result I see in preview (first image) differs from the one I get after clicking OK (second image).

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens with big images. My image was 3200x4000 px. Changed to 1600x2000 px with **Image->Image Size** and the issue was resolved